# Hola, recibo este error al tratar de compilar

Tags: java, android, kotlin

error:

> [RoomProcessor:MiscError] androidx.room.RoomProcessor was unable to
>   process this class because not all of its dependencies could be
>   resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with
>   generated code.
>
> public abstract class StorySaverDatabase extends
>   androidx.room.RoomDatabase { [WARN] Incremental annotation processing
>   requested, but support is disabled because the following processors
>   are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).
>
> A failure occurred while executing
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

```
Archivo Gradle

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "descargar.historias.de.instagram"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.0.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: '83ef4428-dbe5-44d1-9ff5-328f31ef8a19',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.5.8'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.2'

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics dependency.
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // Kotlin
    def nav_version = "2.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.1'

    implementation "androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.4"
    implementation "androidx.tonyodev.fetch2okhttp:xfetch2okhttp:3.1.4"

    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '20030203.000550'
    implementation 'com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:3.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'

    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.5.Final'
    implementation 'com.github.Ferfalk:SimpleSearchView:0.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    def room_version = "2.2.5"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    def work_version = "2.3.4"

    // Kotlin + coroutines
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"

    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.13.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```
Archivo storysaverDatabase.java

package descargar.historias.de.instagram.database

import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = arrayOf(_root_ide_package_.descargar.historias.de.instagram.database.PostEntity::class,
        _root_ide_package_.descargar.historias.de.instagram.database.DownloadEntity::class,
        _root_ide_package_.descargar.historias.de.instagram.database.UserEntity::class), version = 1)
abstract class StorySaverDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun postDao(): _root_ide_package_.descargar.historias.de.instagram.database.PostDao
    abstract fun userDao(): _root_ide_package_.descargar.historias.de.instagram.database.UserDao
}
```

Comment: Hola!, una consulta, que version de Kotlin estas utilizando?

Comment: hola  `buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'`

Answer (score 0):

El problema al parecer es problema viene por el Incremental annotation processing. Pueden ser muchas las causas, así que podrías intentar una de las siguientes:

- Antes de la version 1.3.30, el Incremental Annotation estaba deshabilitado, se tenia que habilitar automáticamente, pero de todas maneras seria bueno revisar si lo tienes deshabilitado. Para esto puedes ingresar a tu archivo `gradle.properties` y verificar el siguiente parámetro

  `kapt.incremental.apt=true`
- Lo que también nos dice la documentación es que  incremental annotation processing requiere que la compilación incremental (incremental compilation) también este habilitado. Entonces podrías verificar en `gradle.properties` lo siguiente:

  `kotlin.incremental=true`
- Finalmente, creo que también deberías verificar si no has cambiado de version a Room y si lo has hecho verificar en la documentación que cambios ha traído y revisar el issuesTracker de google para más información.

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: gracias! voy a revisar y aviso si pude solucionar.